# How do I pass a data type to a resource (.rc) file in Win32 C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources, dialog, constants

I'd like to center a dialog box in my Win32 application, but am having trouble passing constants to my **resource.rc** file. I make the following declaration in **resource.h**:

```
const int SCREENX = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
```

However, when I replace **100** with **SCREENX** in my .rc file (below) and build, I get: **error RC2108: expected numerical dialog constant**.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include "afxres.h"

// I'd like to replace "100" with "GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)"
ID_ABOUT DIALOG DISCARDABLE  100, 0, 237, 87
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About"
FONT 10, "MS Sans Serif"

BEGIN
    GROUPBOX "Contact", IDC_CONTACT, 7, 43, 98, 39, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE
    LTEXT    "My info", IDC_CONTACT, 16, 53, 85, 25, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE
END
```

Neither can I use **GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)** directly in the desired location (same error).

I'd think it would be routine to pass data types to **.rc**, so I must be missing something basic here. (Resource files are giving me no end of headaches.) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resource file is compiled into a bunch of static data that is stored in your executable.  For example, a dialog resource might be compiled into a [`DLGTEMPLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

In other words, everything in a compiled resource is a constant.

`GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)` is not a constant.  It evaluates to the current screen width in pixels at run-time.

As the other answer says, to center your dialog use the `DS_CENTER` style or handle `WM_INITDIALOG`.

Answer (score 1):

To center a Dialog on the screen, just OR the DS_CENTER style to the other window style for the dialog.

If you want to use GetSystemMetrics, do this in WM_INITDIALOG and position the dialog there.

A resource file is just a script.

Comment: To expand on your "A resource file is just a script." It's a script that doesn't have access to any variables defined in the C or C++ source, which is the reason the OP can't use `SCREENX` in the resource file.